# Is SQL Server 2008 Express, not R2, still available?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I need to install the original version of SQL Server 2008 Express, but cannot find it on MS's website, only the newer R2 version. Where can I find an archive of older versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff